# app not using alternative string Resource file

Tags: android, android-resources

I have added another string.xml file in values-zh_rCN. I next set the language on my tablet to Chinese. However. my app is not using the Chinese string.xml inside  the values-zh_rCN folder. I also checked the language set in my tablet in my code by calling:

```
Locale locale = getResources().getConfiguration().locale;
 mCountry = locale.getISO3Country();
```

and it is in fact CHN or China.

What could be the issue here?

Comment: What is the value of `locale.getLanguage()` and `locale.getCountry()`?

Comment: locale.getCountry() -> CN      locale.getLanguage() -> zh

Comment: `locale.toString()`?

Comment: locale.toString() -> zh_CN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your device may be in Chinese, but it is not using the `rCH` or `rTW` country variants, which are the only two officially supported on Android (last I checked). However, device manufacturers can technically support other locale codes such as `zh_CN` in your case.

These easiest solution is simply to move your resources just the `zh` folder to catch all Chinese variants.

If the manufacturer has modified the stock Settings app to add support for `zh_CN`, then you can place resources there as well.

Comment: That was it: I changed my folder name to "values-zh"